How can I exclude .NET 9 updates in Visual Studio Package Manager
The Package Manager in Visual Studio 2022 tries to force me to update System/Microsoft packages to .NET9 versions. But I don't want to use .NET9, instead, stay on the latest .NET8 patch versions.
Is there any way to limit versions in Package Manager to major version 8?
For example:
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 8.0.8
=> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 8.0.11
But not to: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 9.0.0

So, the annoying thing is, that the Updates view always shows me tons of updates, which I don't want, and I have to look up every individual package to check if a patch version within the .net8.0 framework is available.

I get the same issue when checking for updates in Powershell via dotnet command:
dotnet list "Utility.sln" package --source "nuget.org" --framework "net8.0" --outdated

The --framework "net8.0" option doesn't limit new versions to .NET 8 packages.
I am using Central Package Management (CPM), with Directory.Packages.props file for versions.
Temporary workaround
With the dotnet command, the options --highest-minor and --highest-patch exist, but for checking only.
dotnet list "Utility.sln" package --source "nuget.org" --outdated --highest-patch

An alternative for updates is the Package Manager console in Visual Studio itself, or another, similar use of NuGet commands:
Update-Package "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" -ToHighestPatch

or all packages (filter by source, e.g. nuget.org, is also possible).
Update-Package -ToHighestPatch 


Hi @Erik, you can use version ranges to limit he versions of a NuGet package to a specific major version(version 8).

Thank you for sharing, MS is just f.... waste of time...


Is there any way to limit versions in Package Manager to major version 8?

If you want to limit the versions of a NuGet package to a specific major version(version 8), you could use version ranges in your project file like this:
<!-- Accepts any 8.0 version, but not 9.0 and higher.-->
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="[8.0.0,9.0.0)" />

By the way, the doc about --framework  says, "Displays only the packages applicable for the specified target framework."  Based on my test, both the  version 8 and version 9 of this package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore targets net8.
The version 9 of the package does not mean it targets .NET 9.

The version of the package and framework  are two concepts.
Docs Referred:
Package Versioning
dotnet list command

In my case, it was about controlled updates, versions determined in Directory.Packages.props rather than project files. It also has floating versions/ranges available now. I remember from NET 6/7, that NET7 packages would compile and start easily under NET 6, but would result in nasty errors at runtime, because some interfaces or other NET 7 components were missing. I don't want this again with NET 9.

Hi Erik, do you mean you have used floating versions in Directory.Packages.props file but not working?

Most of the Microsoft packages with version 9.0 targets DotNet 9, even though it's not mandatory that all NuGet packages follow this.
